# Angular checkbox filter works reversed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Have an object list

**JS:**

```
$scope.datas = [
        {date:'06-12-2016', name : 'Pinao Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 101, id : 21},
        {date:'15-04-2016', name : 'drivers Class', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 102, id : 22},
        {date:'24-03-2016', name : 'Airplane Class', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 103, id : 23},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 24},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class1', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 241},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class2', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2432},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class3', state: 'notarchived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2342},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class4', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2443},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class5', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2243},
        {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class6', state: 'archived', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104, id : 2242},
];

$scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;
```

Have a filter using checkbox. The idea is to show all items with State:archived

My **HTML:**

```
<th><input ng-model="archived.state"  type="checkbox"
      ng-true-value="'notarchived'" ng-false-value="undefined">Show archived</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate | filter:{state: archived.state}">
        <td>{{paymentinfo.date}}</td>
        <td ng-click="singlepage(paymentinfo.id)">
            <a>{{paymentinfo.name}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="grey-flag remark-payment">
                <div class="hover-remark">{{paymentinfo.remark}}</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</th>
```

Filter works reverse. When I check. show all notarchived elements. need to show archived.
When write like that

```
<input ng-model="archived.state"  type="checkbox"
      ng-true-value="'**archived**'" ng-false-value="undefined">
```

filter want's working work when I write just "archived" and it works when I write  "notarchived", but it works reverse.

https://plnkr.co/edit/lJjTg4rAu9fgjr4wR4ZH?p=preview - set check. will show all notarchived. need to show archived

Comment: plz share a jsfiddle

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/lJjTg4rAu9fgjr4wR4ZH?p=preview

Comment: filter:{state: 'archived'}: archived.state ? true : false modify your filter condition may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
filter:{state: 'archived'}: archived.state ? true : false
```

instead of

```
filter:{state: archived.state}
```

like below.

```
<tr  ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:keyword | filter:money | filter:getdate |  filter:{state: 'archived'}: archived.state ? true : false">
   <td>{{paymentinfo.date}}</td>
   <td ng-click="singlepage(paymentinfo.id)" ><a>{{paymentinfo.name}}</a> </td>
   <td>
      <div class="grey-flag remark-payment">
          <div class="hover-remark">{{paymentinfo.remark}}</div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```